# Flink distributes tasks to one taskmanager until slots is full

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I have a flink cluster with 5 nodes. And each nodes have 8 slots. I am using Flink 1.5.2.

If there are N tasks, the problem is that:

If N <= 8, all tasks will assign to node1.
New tasks will be assigned to node2 until it is full.etc.
And the other nodes will be empty.

I want all tasks distributed to all nodes balanced. Can anybody help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The job manager's scheduler is not aware of which task managers the slots belong to, so no,  it is not possible balance the distribution of tasks.